# Create ListTiles dynamically without a builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a custom-filled ListView which I need to display various types of information (I know, ListView with custom-generated `ListTiles` is probably not the right way to go.) But I want to create some `ListTiles` depending on the amount of Elements I get from another List (usually 1-3 with a max of 4).
I want to display many various Items on those `ListTiles` and want to know how I do this the best way.

My first approach would be creating a new List tile with a for loop and fill it with the data for each entry from the other List.

Like so:

```
Create ListView
Create ListTiles for descriptions
Create ListTile with a checkbox to tick sth off

Get integers from json into an Array
create an additional ListTile for each of those Integers
```

Comment: You want to show value in your `ListTile` depends on some conditiions right?

Comment: Yes and no. i have a json that I extract this specific data from. And depending on the object there are 1-3 sets of data to display additionally. I want to create an amount of list tiles that is equal to those entrys from the json object.

Comment: Still, I am not getting you can you please edit your question with some code/images?

Comment: Unfortunaly, I cannot show any code on this, but I tried to describe the steps as close as possible. Is this explanation better?